# Given a segment $AB$, show that there is a point $C$ on this segment such that $AC=BC$.

Tags: geometry

I'm new to a college level geometry class and with it having been so long since I did geometry back in high school, I'm struggling to figure out this problem.

My college professor isn't the best at explaining doing proofs and this HW is due tomorrow. I was considering doing something with our definition of interior and using some sort of proof with disproving?

All he's really shown so far is disproving. Any help provided would be great!
Interior: "The point $C$ is in the interior of the segment $AB$ if $AC+CB=AB$."
Edit: Here are the axioms, sorry about that!
Axioms
1.Given two points, there exist a unique line containing these two points. For every line there are two points which belong to this line and points which do not.
2.Given there's three points on a line, only one of them can be between the other two.
3. Given a ray CB and positive real number h, there is a unique point A on the ray such that CA=h.
4. To each segment AB we can give a real number AB called the length of this segment. If C is a point between the points A and B, we are able to assume that AC+CB=AB

Comment: Questions like this come down to the axioms you are using.  You need to specify these.

Comment: Hard to effectively answer without knowing what tools the course has given you. Has distance been defined? Are you supposed to know the intermediate value theorem and that distance on a segment is continuous?

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154975/prove-every-segment-has-a-midpoint#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=for%20P%20and%20Q%2Cr,then%20this%20intersection%20always%20exists.) is a duplicate, possibly (again, depending on your choice of axioms).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach that may or may not be consistent with your axioms, depending on whether your class has (also) studied the Pythagorean theorem.

Take any arbitrary radius $~r~$ greater than half the length of $~\overline{AB}.~$  Construct two circles, each of radius $~r,~$ with one circle centered at $~A~$ and the other circle centered at $~B.~$  The two circles will intersect at two points.  Label either one of these two intersection points as point $~D.~$

Within the triangle $\triangle ADB,~$ construct the altitude (i.e. perpendicular) from $~D~$ to $~\overline{AB}.~$  Label the point of intersection (on $~\overline{AB}~$) point $~C.~$

Consider the two **right** triangles $~\triangle ADC~$ and $~\triangle BDC.~$  By construction, you have that $~\overline{AD} = \overline{BD}.~$

Therefore, by the pythagorean theorem, you have that

$$\overline{AC} = \sqrt{\overline{AD}^2 -\overline{CD}^2} = \sqrt{\overline{BD}^2 -\overline{CD}^2} = \overline{BC}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be the length of AB (axiom 4). Then use axiom 3 (understanding that the validity of the axiom is not connected with how we have decided to name the points involved) with $h=L/2$ (i.e., the axiom means that on the ray AB there is a unique point C with AC=$h$). (Hopefully you are allowed to assume that real numbers can be divided by 2.) Finally, you should probably use axiom 2 and axiom 4 together to explicitly show that C is the point which is in the interior of the segment (assume A or B is between the other two points and then show there is a contradiction of axiom 4).

Answer (score 0):

I have another possible solution quite similar to the solution of @user2661923.

Consider the circles $O$ and $O'$ with centers $A$ and $B$, respectively, and radius $r=\overline{AB}$.

We have that $O\cap O'=\{D,D'\}$. The line joining $D$ and $D'$ will meet $AB$ at a point $C$. That is your point. To see that you can prove that the triangles $\triangle ACD$ and $\triangle BCD$ are "similar".

Notice that $\triangle ADB$ and $\triangle AD'B$ are equilateral with side $r$.